# How to Compare dateandtime field of sql database from current date where dateandtime is in June 06, 2019 at 11:19AM this format in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, mysql-workbench

I want to compare date of database from current date but not able to. Have tried `DATE_FORMAT`, `FROM_UNIXTIME`, `DATE`, `STR_TO_DATE` but nothing is working. They are returning NULL only.

`DateAndTime` column in "June 12, 2019 at 03:24PM" this format and type is `VARCHAR`.

```
SELECT User, 
  DATE_FORMAT(DateAndTime,'%d-%m-%Y') AS AddDate
FROM CallList
```

Comment: What is the datatype of your column

Comment: its varchar @Jens

Comment: Why you declare this column as `VARCHAR`? This column should be of type `DATETIME` and at origin you can create one `DATETIME` from this string and insert into the database.

Comment: It is not a good idea to store dates as varchat. use a date type

Comment: Can't we use in varchar only because previously other person was working on this I can't change type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get a [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) value using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('June 12, 2019 at 03:24PM', '%M %d, %Y at %h:%i%p')
-- 2019-06-12 15:24:00

-- example for comparison
SELECT * 
FROM `CallList` 
WHERE NOW() > STR_TO_DATE('June 12, 2019 at 03:24PM', '%M %d, %Y at %h:%i%p')
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99aec03d721e0a57d3091e37f3f44a48)

So the following query should work:

```
SELECT `User`,
  STR_TO_DATE(`DateAndTime`, '%M %d, %Y at %h:%i%p') AS `AddDate`
FROM `CallList`
```

I recommend to replace the `DateAndTime` column with a real `DATETIME` column instead of storing the datetime value as string.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `str_to_date()`?

```
str_to_date(DateAndTime, '%M %d, %Y at %I:%i%p')
```

Important note: *never* store dates as strings. This is harmful in many ways: it is inefficicent, and will add useless complexity to all your queries (which you are starting to see). I would highly recommend fixing your data model to store dates in the relevant `date` datatype.

Here is a migration procedure skeleton:

```
-- create a new column and populate it
alter table CallList add DateAndTime2 datetime;
update CallList set DateAndTime2 = str_to_date(DateAndTime, '%M %d, %Y at %I:%i%p');

-- drop the old column and rename the new colum
alter table CallList drop column DateAndTime;
alter table CallList change DateAndTime2 DateAndTime datetime;
```